# Javascript Convert String to Object(list/array)

Tags: javascript

Problem 1: Can this be achieved in javascript?

```
value = "['iPhone', 'iBall']"
```

to

```
value = ['iPhone', 'iBall']
```

Problem 2:
To make it harder, The values are encoded:

```
value = "[&#x27;iPhone&#x27;, &#x27;iball&#x27;]"
```

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  Can you get the data in a "proper" JSON format to begin with?  Otherwise, you'll have to "convert" this to JSON.

Comment: I'm a django developer. so from backend im sending a list(array) and in forntend JS script i'm recieving it but its coming as encoded like i said in problem 2.

Comment: It sounds like you need to fix this on the back-end.  You should be able to properly JSON encode the data so the front-end can easily parse it.

Comment: For any django developers this might help. just use `{{ value|safe }}` instead of `'{{ value }}'` do not include double or single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help ?

```js
var value = "['iPhone', 'iBall']";
value = JSON.parse(value.replaceAll(`'`, `"`));
console.log(value);


value = "[&#x27;iPhone&#x27;, &#x27;iball&#x27;]";
value = JSON.parse(value.replaceAll(`&#x27;`, `"`));
console.log(value);
console.log(typeof(value));
```

Comment: This will work for the text values given, but if there were any other special characters inside the values (&, for example) I suspect it would be encoded by the server as well. I think the right solution is to solve this in the back end and return valid JSON.

Comment: @Pranav Rustagi Yeah the answer works fine. But If you check the typeof value is still string.

Comment: Thanks for all. I solved my probelm with the help of this answer as well as few backend changes. Previously i was sending `{'key': ['values']}` Not working well. so added nested dict. `{key: {key: ['values']}}` worked. Even this approach got me an encoded response but after replacing it(above solution). it worked well.

Comment: @AndyMerts I don't think that there will be any problem with special characters as I'm using `replaceAll()` which will replace the occurrences of Apostrophe, both `( ' )`, as well as encoded `(&#x27;)`,  with ` " `.

Comment: @jeevu94 the type of `value` was object (array), and not string. I just didn't assigned the object to `value` variable, and generated console directly.